# Showing that a function $u:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

> How does one show if one function $u:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable?

Using Schilling's [methodology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1316620247), I understand this as to show that $u$ is $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$ measurable (see Chapter 8), where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $[a,b]$. To do this, one may show that, for example, $\{u<\alpha\}\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

> Is this automatically true, if $u$ were continuous on $[a,b]$?

Here is what I did,

$\{u<\alpha\}=\{x\in [a,b]:u(x)<\alpha\}=u^{-1}((-\infty,\alpha))$

Then the right hand side is open, because of continuity. But does it belong to $\mathcal{A}$?

> Another question is, no sure if it is relevant, what if $u$ were not continuous on $[a,b]$?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that 'measurable functions' are to 'measures' as 'continuous functions' are to 'topologies', in the sense that $f$ is measurable iff the preimage of measurable sets under $f$ is measurable. This of course begs the question: what are the measures on the domain and codomain of $f$? The 'same' $f$ may or may not be measurable depending on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 2 examples:

(1) $\mathcal{A}=\sigma\{[a,(a+b)/2),[(a+b)/2,b]\}$ and $u(x)=x$ ($u$ is not $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable).

(2) $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. generated from open sets) and $u$ is continuous ($u$ is $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$-measurable according to your argument).

Regarding your second question, there are discontinuous functions that are measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{A}$ in (1), e.g. $u(x)=1_{[a,(a+b)/2)}(x)$, and there exist functions that are not measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{A}$ in (2) (which is much larger), e.g. $u(x)=1_N(x)$, where $N$ is a non-Borel set in $[a,b]$.